# SSAS MDX Query not filtering dimensions based on roles

Tags: ssas, mdx, roles, cube

I have a windows application showing business intelligence and analysis data through MDX queries running on cubes in ssas.

In this way, I have added roles to Cubes with dimension data filtering but some mdx queries are not filtering data like mdx queries without any dimension as shown below.

`SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Amt] } ON COLUMNS  FROM [SalesCube]`

The above query is not showing data as per the dimensions filtered in dimension data of the role.

But queries having dimensions are filtered.

Please let me know how to handle this scenario.

Comment: The query you included includes every cube dimension but they will all be set to the default `[All]` member - do you have security set for the All member/levels?

Comment: Seems like the visual totals issue which is explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466562/ssas-dimension-data-permissions-not-applied-to-measures-when-the-dimension-is-no/26470054#26470054

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Enable Visual Totals" to allow role mdx to be applied to all kind of queries, even not specifying dimension itself

Check your role - Dimension data - Advanced, at the bottom